# Getting latest version in TFS is not working properly

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, source-control-explorer

I'm using TFS for synchronizing my works with my partner on out project. But I have many problems with this. When my partner added some new files to the project and I want to have this files is my local version.

At first I tried to get it by right-click on project in solution explorer and selecting "Get Latest Version". But this method did not get the new files.

Then I went to Source Control and selected all the files and folders in project and pressed "Get Latest Version". The new files downloaded, but it seems that files are not a part of the project. They are just downloaded, but the don't appear in solution explorer near other file.

What is the problem here? Thanks.

Comment: I think you're going to have to explain in detail your entire workflow, because this is not normal.

Comment: Has your partner checked in the project file? If so did you get the latest of that file as well as the code files?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. And the issue is that the files are hidden in the solution explorer. You can see them if you click "Show All Files", and then right click the files and "Include in Project". But it shouldnt be like this, why do I have to include all those files, they should be automatically included.

Comment: I get a similar (and, by the sound of it, related) problem on a daily basis. TFS will retrieve files within projcets, but never the .sln files or .csproj files.

Answer (score 1):

Is your solution and project files [bound to Source control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181375%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in TFS? That is one of the things I can come up with with your description.

Answer (score 0):

Those files may be added after mapping is done I think. Also, as @James Reed suggested, those files may not be checked-in.

If those are not the cases, I recommend a "Remove Mapping" and "Mapping" again.

Hope this helps.